# Angular 2 how to fade rest of page on slide in

Tags: css, angular

I would love to provide a screenshot of what I want to accomplish, but its proprietary designs and can't so I'll do my best to describe what I want.

I apologize in advance as I'm not the most fluent front-end developer but am learning new things everyday.  I have a slide in on my page when a user clicks a button which also performs an angular 2 animation:
TypeScript:

```
animations: [
 trigger('slide', [
  state('true', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
  })),
  state('false', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)'
  })),
  transition('1 => 0', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
  transition('0 => 1', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
 ]),
]
....
 openBucket(nb) {
   this.bucketState = true;
   nb.openBucket(this.bucketState);
 }
```

HTML:

```
....
<div class="review-button" (click)="openBucket(nb)"></div>
<new-bucket #nb [@slide]="bucketState"></new-bucket>
...
```

So before it opens, the page looks normal, but after the slide in I want the left side to be overlayed with a semi-transparent blue which is flush against the slider.  How is this done?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need, what it's called, a veil screen. It has the full screen size and has opacity set less that 1, like 0.6. It can have a  certain background-color (blue in your case). And you display it when the slide is opened.

Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div @someAnimation class="veil" *ngIf="bucketState"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .veil{
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       overflow: hidden;
       height:100vh;
       width:100vw;
       backgound-color: blue;
       opacity:0;
       z-index: 2 // should be more than the rest of the screen but less than the slide
    }
```

**Animation:**

```
 trigger('someAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            animate('900ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            style({ opacity: 1 }),
            animate('900ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 0 }))
        ])
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It looks like the veil is pushing the content on the page rather than overlaying on top of it.  Would you know why that is?

Comment: I was able to fix this with
position:fixed;
top:0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;

Thank you!